# SQL query select to put in variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables, ms-access

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = runsql("select Question_Topic, Question_Difficuilty from QuestionMutli) where Question_Topic = '" & quiztopic & "' and Question_Difficuilty = " & DifficultyLevel & "")
```

I wrote this code to put records in the `dt` variable if they match the quiz topic variable and the difficulty level variable but when the program runs the `dt = ...` line it comes up with:

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator)
 in query expression 'Question_Difficuilty QuestionMutli Topic where 
Question_Topic = 'Algebra And Functions' and Question_Difficuilty = 1'.'
```

The quiz topic variable is string and the difficulty level is an integer. It is with MS Access.

Does anyone know what is causing the syntax error?

Comment: Does your table name contains brackets?

Comment: You almost certainly do not have a table named `Question(mutli)`.  Read [ask] and take the [tour[, please

Comment: Please, check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You should add `[]` brackets around a table name.

Comment: @bob smith Please review "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to be a very simple SQL query" and then update your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Don't use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention and will have fewer headaches. Is `mutli` a misspelling? Should be `multi`?

Comment: i have fixed the table name but it says i a mission an operator, plus the table name is a mistake with mutli but i am sticking with it now

Comment: What does runsql look like?

Comment: Based on the answer by @dvallejo what about using this code? 

`Dim dt As New DataTable  
dt = runsql("select Question_Topic, Question_Difficuilty from QuestionMutli) where Question_Topic = '" & quiztopic & "' and Question_Difficuilty = " & DifficultyLevel & "") `

Comment: @bobf You don't need the final & "" : `Dim dt As New DataTable dt = runsql("select Question_Topic, Question_Difficuilty from QuestionMutli where Question_Topic = '" & quiztopic & "' and Question_Difficuilty = " & DifficultyLevel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra close paren after your table name QuestionMutli.